# Why is my Perl regex using so much memory?

Tags: regex, perl, memory-management

I'm running a regular expression against a large scalar.  Though this match isn't capturing anything, my process grows by 30M after this match:

```
# A
if (${$c} =~ m/\G<<\s*/cgs)
{
    #B
    ...
}
```

`$c` is a reference to a pretty big scalar (around 21M), but I've verified that `pos(${$c})` is in the right place and the expression matches at the first character, with `pos(${$c})` being updated to the correct place after the match.  But as I mentioned, the process has grown by about 30M between #A and #B, even though I'm not capturing anything with this match.  Where is my memory going?

Edit:  Yes, use of `$&` was to blame.  We are using Perl 5.8.8, and my script was using [Getopt::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Getopt-Declare), which uses the built-in [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text::Balanced).  The 1.95 version of this module was using `$&`.  The 2.0.0 version that ships with Perl 5.10 has removed the reference to `$&` and alleviates the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just a quick sanity check, are you mentioning $&, $` or $' (sometimes called $MATCH, $PREMATCH and $POSTMATCH) anywhere in your code?  If so, Perl will copy your entire string for *every* regular expression match, just in case you want to inspect those variables.

"In your code" in this case means indirectly, including using modules that reference these variables, or writing `use English` rather than `use English qw( -no_match_vars )`.

If you're not sure, you can use the [Devel::SawAmpersand](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::SawAmpersand) module to determine if they have been used, and [Devel::FindAmpersand](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::FindAmpersand) to figure out *where* they are used.

There may be other reasons for the increase in memory (which version of Perl are you using?), but the match variables will definitely blow your memory if they're used, and hence are a likely culprit.

Cheerio,

*Paul*

Comment: Certainly looks like that's it.  I can't run FindAmpersand on my perl because I have threads enabled, so I'm recompiling perl just to run this test, but SawAmpersand is reporting yes.

Comment: grep or ack should also be able to tell you if they are mentioned anywhere in your code.

Comment: Tried that and didn't find anything in my code, so finally started grepping through all the libraries in @INC, and finally narrowed it down to GetOpt::Declare, which was using $&.  Getting rid of that library went a long way to fixing my memory use problems.